# How would I find what page a user comes from?

Tags: detect, referrer

I am looking for a way to detect which page a user comes from (the users referring page). If the user does not come from a page called "index.php", they should be redirected to a page, like, google.com. Any programming language that can be embedded into an html file. Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult even to begin to list the ways in which this question is unclear. Could you give a few more specifics on your setup, what you're trying to achieve and what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the previouse url by :
 $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

in some cases this can be forbidden by the browser user settings

> 'HTTP_REFERER' The address of the page (if any) which referred the
>   user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all
>   user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify
>   HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

check it on the php manual
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [HTTP Referer header field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTTP referrer header: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

There's a tutorial [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blref.htm) on how to access it using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the header called `Referer` [sic] . See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html (section 14.36)

Obtain its value however you want.